# How to return access_token in response body instead of #access_token in the url?

Tags: url, callback, auth0

I'm writing a Go application which has to authenticate using auth0. This is done similar to how Google do it, by creating a HTTP server and setting the callback url to localhost
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp

Instead of sending the access_token in the HTTP body, it stored the token in the URL which could be cached by the browser/proxy.

http://127.0.0.1:36572/auth0/authenticate/#access_token=eyJ0...truncated...SVYsfTThUhssJSh2C9FSvSGFusdw&expires_in=7200&token_type=Bearer&state=QuSsUxSZkYtFi7QPJkpxB9VI23lO3x4W

How do I configure auth0 to make the callback request to http://127.0.0.1:36572/auth0/authenticate, and store the sensitive tokens in the HTTP response body?

Thanks

EDIT: https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/authorization-code-grant-pkce

Comment: Are you writing a "regular web app"? If so, you would receive a code and exchange that for the token(s) securely using confidential client on server side. Check your request, and value of `response_type` (should be `code`)

Comment: thanks https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/authorization-code-grant-pkce